# Make nerdtree use the same nerdtree buffer when entering many directories

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

In `nerdtree`, if I enter many directories and then open the file I want, my screen would look like this:

```
| nerdTree window |  Tab1:directory1 | Tab2:directory2 | Tab3: file1 |
```

Tab1 and Tab2 are not needed because the file I am interested in is not in, they are just on my path to file which is shown on Tab3

What I want is this:

```
| nerdTree window | Tab3: file |
```

And then if I happen to open a different file, which requires me to navigate to many different folders; after I press `Enter` on that file while in `nerdtree`:

```
| nerdTree window | file1 | file2 (just visited by pressing Enter on nerdtree |
```

Is this possible? Please let me know

Comment: First I think you should provide some screenshots because it is not completely clear what you are talking about. I don't understand what it means to have your screen looking like a line with a window and some tabs. Also as often with nerdtree related questions I would recommend reading [this article](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) and maybe considering a switch to netrw instead of nerdtree.